# First order logic assignment

Tags: variable-assignment, assign, first-order-logic

I don't understand the assignment in this image:

[image]

respectively:

> α[x↦a](x)=a
>   α[x↦a](y)=α(y)  for y≠x

Someone,can help me?

Comment: I've inlined the image. I presume your confusion is with the two that have "if for (some/every) *a*...". Can you explain what parts of it you do (think you) understand and what part(s) are confusing to you please (please [edit] your question to add this information)

Comment: I'm sorry. Done!

Answer (score 0):

We start with `α` being an assignment. These final lines are saying that `α[x↦a]` produces a *new* assignment. In this new assignment (first line), `x` is now `a`. And for all other variables that aren't `x` (second line), whatever they were in the old assignment `α` is what they still are in this new assignment.

Both lines have to be read/interpreted together.

(Apologies if some of my terminology is a bit off in the above. I haven't had to discuss this topic for quite a long time)

Comment: Ok i understand your explanation.So y is used to say for all other variables doesn’t change nothing.is correct?

Comment: @Luca - yep, `y` is a metavariable here, standing for other variables.